# Functions, and Image importing

Tags: javascript, html, sprite

I'm working on a project in game development in Javascript and HTML5 canvas. I have this common code I use for loading sprites:

```
var sprite = new Image();
sprite.src = "sprite.png";
```

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this, which I first thought by function, but not sure how I should do so. I would think to do so like this:

```
function loadSprite(src) {
this.src = src;
}
var loadSprite(sprite.png);
```

However I don't think this is the right way to do it. Could someone correct my code and/or give a simpler way of loading an image like this? (I am also using a ctx.drawImage(..., sprite) in order to change coordinates on the canvas so it needs an x,y,width,and height parameters in one way or another)

Comment: well you need an image object.... and your second code does not have one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use as below:

```
function loadSprite(src) {
var sprite = new Image();
sprite.src = src;
return sprite
}

var _local_var = loadSprite('sprite.png');
```